# Reference Request: Prereqs for Lecture Notes on "Abstract Linear Algebra"

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, soft-question

I just found [this set of lecture notes](http://users.ipfw.edu/CoffmanA/pdf/book.pdf) on linear algebra which seems to go over several things I've been wondering about as I study linear algebra.  Unfortunately there are very few exercises in the text and I'm not even positive I have the skill to prove the first few lemmas myself.  I have read the first couple of sections so far, and I think I understand the material as well I as can while not having any exercises to practice on -- which is *not well enough*.  So my question is:

> Is there a book/ reference which goes over this same material, but can be more easily self-studied?  Or else can anyone recommend a text which will at least prepare me enough to be able to figure these lecture notes out on my own?

Comment: I think studying category theory will be more helpful to understand those notes. Once you have a foundational understanding of that, you should study bilinear maps/forms and be familiar with the properties of trace (you could do this first in fact before category theory).